# Is there any cheaper way for multiplying a plaintext scalar to a vector?

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

Assume I am using the SIMD encryption of homomorphic encryption. Performing plaintext-ciphertext multiplication between two vectors $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{x}$ means
$Dec(\mathbf{a} \times Enc(\mathbf{x})) = \mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{x}$, where $\times$ means point-wise (or say element-wise) multiplication.  I am wondering if all elements of $\mathbf{a}$ is the same. Is there any cheaper way to do this multiplication?

A possible way I have known is to use the square and multiply algorithm, adding $\mathbf{x}$ to itself to multiply its plaintext by two, which allows to multiply in times $O(\log_2a)$.

Comment: What does $\vec a\times \vec x$ mean to you? Point-wise multiplication of vectors, or what?

Comment: Yes, point-wise multiplication.

Comment: Which FHE scheme are we talking about?

Comment: Like CKKS? I do not want to limit the discussion to a specific scheme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any **cheaper** way to do this multiplication?

This word has two natural interpretations

1. Cheaper **computation**, and
2. Cheaper **noise growth**.

For 1, the answer is "no".
Additionally, your square-and-multiply algorithm is not necessary.
To efficiently (from the perspective of computation) compute your desired quantity, you format ciphertexts as

$$\mathsf{Enc}(\mathsf{iNTT}_p(\vec x)).$$

Here, $\mathsf{iNTT}_p(\vec x)$ is the inverse $\mathsf{NTT}$ modulo $p$, your plaintext modulus.
This maps $\vec x\in(\mathbb{Z}_p^n, +, \circ)$ (where $\circ$ is the [Hadamard product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)), what you notate as $\times$) to a polynomial $f_{\vec x}(X)\in \mathbb{Z}_p[x]/(X^n+1)$.
There are some conditions for this map to exist ($p$ needs to be "NTT friendly"), but they are common in practice.

When formatted this way, we can compute

$$\mathsf{iNTT}_p(\vec a), \mathsf{Enc}(\mathsf{iNTT}_p(\vec x))\mapsto \mathsf{iNTT}_p(\vec a)\ast \mathsf{Enc}(\mathsf{iNTT}_p(\vec x)) = \mathsf{Enc}(\mathsf{iNTT}_p(\vec a\circ \vec x)).$$

Here, $\ast$ is polynomial multiplication. Often in practice you work in the "NTT domain".
Then, this would instead look like

$$\vec a, \mathsf{NTT}_p(\mathsf{Enc}(\mathsf{iNTT}_p(\vec x)))\mapsto \vec a\circ \mathsf{NTT}_p(\mathsf{Enc}(\mathsf{iNTT}_p(\vec x))) = \mathsf{NTT}_p(\mathsf{Enc}(\mathsf{iNTT}_p(\vec a\circ \vec x))).$$

This all being said, the noise growth for this operation will be large.
Even if $\vec a$ is small, $\mathsf{iNTT}_p(\vec x)$ may be large (it probably has $\ell_\infty$-norm bounded by $p$). Perhaps your setting can handle this, but if it can't then even though this is "cheap" from the perspective of computational efficiency (something like $O(n)$ operations in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ if you are already in the NTT domain, otherwise $O(n\log n)$), it is "expensive" from the perspective of noise growth.

For 2, the answer is (sort of) also "no".
One typically uses a variant of square-and-multiply, though different from how you are imagining.

The issue we ran into before is that we are polynomial-multiplying by $\mathsf{iNTT}_p(\vec a)$, which may be large.
We can polynomial=multiply by a smaller quantity as follows.
Scalar $y$, write

$$y = \sum_{i = 0}^{\ell - 1} g^{-1}(y) g_i$$

where $\vec g\in\mathbb{Z}_q^\ell$ is a "Gadget".
Explicitly, you can think of $\vec g = (1, 2, 2^2, ..., 2^{\ell-1})$ for $\ell = \lceil \log_2(q)\rceil$.
The notation $g^{-1}(y)$ "gadget decomposition".
For the aformentioned binary digit decomposition gadget, this maps

$$y \mapsto (\vec y_{0},\dots, y_{\ell-1})$$

where $y_i\in\{0,1\}$ are such that

$$\langle g^{-1}(y), \vec g\rangle = y$$

Note that this defines gadget decomposition for scalars.
Extend to vectors by decomposing each scalar in the vector independently.

Anyway, now if you instead format the ciphertexts as

$$\mathsf{Enc}(\vec g\otimes \mathsf{iNTT}_p(\vec x)) :=\mathsf{Enc}(g_0\mathsf{iNTT}_p(\vec x)), \mathsf{Enc}(g_1\mathsf{iNTT}_p(\vec x)),\dots \mathsf{Enc}(g_{\ell-1}\mathsf{iNTT}_p(\vec x)),$$

e.g. you increase the number of ciphertexts you have by a factor $\ell$, then you can "square and multiply" to get a homomorphic operation

$$\mathsf{iNTT}_p(\vec a), \mathsf{Enc}(\vec g\otimes \mathsf{iNTT}_p(\vec x)))\mapsto \sum_{i\in[\ell]} g^{-1}(\mathsf{iNTT}_p(\vec a))\ast\mathsf{Enc}(g_i \mathsf{iNTT}_p(\vec x)).$$

This yields multiplication by $\mathsf{iNTT}_p(\vec a)$ with noise growth that scales with $\approx 2\ell$ (and for digit decomposition with respect to base $B$, it becomes $\approx B\lceil \log_B q\rceil$), which can sometimes be useful.

Comment: Does cheaper computation works in any scheme? What about the cost of converting back and foreword from spectral domain.

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer! But I am confused about why the NNT and INNT are needed. It seems increases the overhead. Moreover, the answer seems to be a general  algorithm for any $a$ while I am wondering a special case where all elements in $a$ are the same. Looking forward to your reply.

Comment: @kelalaka you need a plaintext modulus such that you have an isomorphism $(\mathbb{Z}_p^n, +, \circ)\cong \mathbb{Z}_p[x]/(x^n+1)$. This requires the plaintext modulus $p\equiv 1\bmod 2n$ to be NTT friendly. It is a common assumption in things like BGV/BFV encryption. And the cost of computing to/from the NTT domain is required here, as otherwise you do not have pointwise multiplication of values, only polynomial multiplication, which is not what the OP wanted.

Comment: @ZhengyiLi Sorry, I didn't see that all elements of $a$ are the same. Then you can do this with polynomial multiplication, e.g. you can just encrypt via $\mathsf{Enc}(\vec x)$ (viewing $\vec x$ as the coefficients of a polynomial), and multiply all coefficients by $a$ by multiplying your two components of your ciphertext $(c_0(x), c_1(x))$ by the constant polynomial $a$. Square and multiply still seems unnecessary here though, solely because multiplication by $a$ likely occurs in a single underlying instruction, so square-and-multiply would only make things slower for no reason.

Comment: Square-and-multiply may still be useful to reduce the noise growth via gadgets, but that doesn't sound like your primary concern. Overall, plaintext-ciphertext multiplications are very efficient in FHE, so if they areyour bottleneck for some reason it might make sense to describe your application more.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I understand correctly, directly multiplying $a$ to the ciphertext $(c_0(x), c_1(x))$ increases the noise to $a$ times. But since $a$ is defined on a small field, so the noise growth is still acceptable. Is this right?